# How to create a recursive 'show' method for list node in linked list from the end to start?

Tags: java, recursion

I got two prepared classes, one for 'List'(linked list) and one for 'ListNode', and they asked my (for homework) to create a recursive 'showRev' methods for the 'List' class that uses another 'showRev' method of ListNode class...

What this method should do is show the list but from the end to start, the opposite of show.

So I need two methods, but that the 'List' one will use the 'ListNode' one.

This is my code:

```
public class List {

    private ListNode firstNode;
    private ListNode lastNode;
    private String name;


    public List()
    {
        this("list");
    }


    public List(String listName)
    {
        name=listName;
        firstNode=lastNode=null;
    }
.
.
.
.//there are more methods here
.
.
.
public void showRev()
    {
        //what do you suggest?
    }
```

And this is the ListNode class:

```
public class ListNode {

    Object data;
    ListNode nextNode;


    public ListNode(Object o)
    {
        this(o,null);
    }


    public ListNode(Object o,ListNode node)
    {
        data=o;
        nextNode=node;
    }


    public Object getObject()
    {
        return data;
    }


    public ListNode getNext()
    {
        return nextNode;
    }


    public void show () 
    {
        System.out.println(this.getObject());
        if (this.nextNode != null) {
            this.nextNode.show();
        }
    }


    public void showRev ()
    {
        // what do you suggest?
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to give you an answer, but rather give you some ideas that should lead you to an answer.

When you want to solve a problem with recursion, you break down your problem into one or more smaller instances of the same problem.

In this case, you have a `List`.  You can break that down into "the first node" and "the rest of the list".  The "rest of the list" is a smaller instance of the same problem.

If your problem is to display the `List` in reverse order, and you already had a magic way to display "the rest of the list" in reverse order, then how could you solve the problem?  This will take a little thought.  If you get stuck, try thinking about lists of just two or three elements.

If you can figure that out, then you have the answer.  The "magic way" to display the rest of the list will be a recursive call.  Then all you need to do is figure out when to stop (the "base case"): at what point do you want the method to stop calling itself recursively?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your method do something like this to print reverse list via recursion.

```
 public void showRev(ListNode node)
  {
    if (node != null) {
      showRev(node.nextNode);
      System.out.println(node.data);
    };
  }
```